# Desabilitar Menu da MasterPage a partir de uma contentPage

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um pequeno menu na Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="INTEGRASYS.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title> ::INTEGRASYS::</title>
    <link href="~/Styles/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <header>

                <ul>
                    <li class = "liultimo"><a href = "index.aspx" > ADM SYS </a></li>
                    <li> <a href = "administrativo.aspx" > Administrativo </a></li>
                    <li> <a href = "" > Executivo </a></li>
                    <li> <a href = "" > Comercial </a></li>
                    <li> <a href = "" > Técnico </a></li>
                </ul>
        </header>
. . .
```

Minha página inicial é a de *login* (`login.aspx`). O que eu quero fazer é deixar desabilitados esses itens de lista (`li`) e habilita-los após o *login*, na página `index.aspx`

O *login* já está funcionando e redireciona para a `index.aspx`.

Comment: Se estiver guardando o usuário em algum lugar após o login (Session por exemplo), você pode por um `if` na sua `<ul>` para caso a `Session` do usuário esteja `null`, não exiba os menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução possível, é você deixar as `<li>` que não serão exibidas dentro de um `Panel`.

```
<ul>
    <li class="liultimo"><a href="index.aspx" >ADM SYS</a></li>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" Visible="False" ID="pnlEsconder">
        <li><a href="administrativo.aspx">Administrativo</a></li>
    </asp:Panel>
    <li><a href="">Executivo</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Comercial</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Técnico</a></li>
</ul>
```

e no `code behind`, da `Content Page`, verificar se o Usuário está logado, e mostrar o panel.

```
var pnlEsconder = (Panel)Master.FindControl("pnlEsconder");
if (Session["logado"] != null) pnlEsconder.Visible = true;
```